# How would I loop through all csv filenames in a certain folder in my directory and perform a string split on those filenames?

Tags: r

I am trying to loop through all csv filenames in a certain folder directory on my computer. Once this is done I want to be perform a string split on the filenames. Is there a way an efficient way of doing this?

At the moment I am entering the string of the filename manually in my code and them performing the string split on that string but this is not efficient...

```
file <- "test_1.csv"
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: What string split are you trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the working directory is set on the folder where we want to extract the file names, use `list.files`

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = FALSE, ignore.case = TRUE)
```

and use `regex` to extract

```
sub("\\.csv", "", files)
```

Or use a convenient function from the `tools` package

```
tools::file_path_sans_ext(files)
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I have set the working directory and this works really well! I used the regex to extract but just out of curiosity can you explain the function from the tools package?

Comment: @Lynda It is a package available when you install `base R`.  It extracts the string before the extension ie. `.csv` part would be removed

Comment: Ok thanks for clarifying @akrun! So it pretty much does the same thing as the regex.

Comment: +1 I use this all the time.  You may want to add `ignore.case = TRUE` in case there are any ".CSV" files in there.  There are other useful switches for directory searching etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run something like this
Directory.GetFiles(DirectoryOfAllTheCSVFiles, "*.csv")

This will create a collection of all the CSV files with the file path. Then run through collection and do something like this

Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)

It will return the file name without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Read all the files in a given folder. First, save the route.

```
files <- list.files(path = "//server/route/folder", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)
```

Then, read all at the same time and turn it into a dataframe.

```
data <-  sapply(files, read_csv, simplify=FALSE)%>%bind_rows(.id = "column_name_here_for_each_file")
```